# How can I implement a strategy pattern for returning a structure that's declared private?

Tags: f#

**How can I implement a strategy pattern for returning a structure that's declared private?**

Or translated...

**How do I restrict the creation of a private structure to more than one function?**

I want to implement an IOlogin interpreter and a MockLogin interpreter for a user login operation. The two functions should return a value of type *AuthenticatedManager*.

Getting started, I wanted to define a type in a module like this:

```
module Specification =

    type AuthenticatedManager = private { Name:string }
```

The code above is meant to restrict the creation of an *AuthenticatedManager*.

I want to reference *AuthenticatedManager* in a separate module:

```
module Mock =

    open Specification

    let username =        Username "test_manager"
    let password =        Password "123"
    let invalidPassword = Password "invalid password"

    let login username' password' : Result<AuthenticatedManager,Username*string> =

        if  ( username',password') = ( username,password  )

        then  Ok    { Name="authenticated manager" } // compile error
        else  Error ( username',"Failed to login" )
```

I know that the compile error stems from me trying to reference a private structure outside of the module that I declared it in. However, I believe it makes sense to have separate libraries to accommodate interpreters for this type of operation.

Answer (score 5):

You should define a module for each type with a private constructor and have `create` and `value` functions for the type in that module.  The module should be in the same compilation unit as the type, so it can access the private constructor.  The following is a simple example of a pattern I use all the time:

```
[<Struct>] type Username = private Username of string

// Make one module for each type
module Username =
    let create = function // Use whatever the real business rules are here
    | username when not <| String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) -> Ok <| Username username
    | _ -> Error "Username must not be blank"

    let value (Username username) = username
```

Then, anywhere you need a `Username`, you call the `create` function that has access to the private constructor, and it validates the data and builds it for you.  Likewise, anywhere you need to extract the raw `string` from the `Username`, you use the `value` function.

Answer (score 0):

I added a strategy function (i.e. *AuthenticationStrategy *) to the same containing module that the *private* constructor was declared in.

I was then able to compile without any issues.

**Specification**

```
namespace Access.Specification

type Username = Username of string
type Password = Password of string

type AuthenticationStrategy = Username -> Password -> unit -> bool

type AuthenticatedManager = private { Name:string }

let authenticate username password strategy : AuthenticatedManager option = 

    if strategy username password ()
    then Some { Name= "username" }
    else None
```

**Mock**

```
let login username' password' : Result<AuthenticatedManager,Username*string> =

    let strategy username'' password'' () =

        if  ( username'',password'') = ( username,password  )
        then true
        else false

    authenticate username' password' strategy 
     |> function
        | Some manager -> Ok manager
        | None         -> Error <| (username',"Login failed")
```

**Gateway**

```
module Access.Gateway

open Mobile.Core

let login username password : Result<AuthenticatedManager,Username*string> =

    let strategy username' password' () =
        // IO Logic goes here...
        true

    authenticate username password strategy
     |> function
        | Some manager -> Ok        manager
        | None         -> Error <| (username,"Login failed")
```

**Appendix**

```
module AppLogic.Configuration

open Access
open Access.Specification.Login
open Access.Specification
open TestAPI

type Environment = DEV | QA | PROD

type Dependencies = {
    Environment:    Environment
    ServerLogin:    Login.Attempt
    ForgotPassword: Login.PasswordRequest
}

let configure = function

    | DEV  -> { Environment=      DEV
                ServerLogin=    { Login=   Mock.login;          Endpoint= Endpoint "n/a" }
                ForgotPassword= { Forgot=  Mock.forgotPassword; Endpoint= Endpoint "n/a" }
              }
    | QA   -> { Environment=      QA
                ServerLogin=    { Login=   Gateway.login;       Endpoint= Endpoint "http://..." }
                ForgotPassword= { Forgot=  Mock.forgotPassword; Endpoint= Endpoint "http://..." }
              }
    | PROD -> { Environment=      PROD
                ServerLogin=    { Login=   Gateway.login;       Endpoint= Endpoint "http://..." }
                ForgotPassword= { Forgot=  Mock.forgotPassword; Endpoint= Endpoint "http://..." }
              }
```

Comment: Why have the constructor be private if you're just going to have a public function that does the same thing?  Generally the idea with private constructors is to only have one publicly accessible way to create the type, and then model the business rules in that one place, such that any instance of the type is guaranteed to have met the rules.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated the code with AuthenticationStrategy. I'm curious what your thoughts are on the latest update.

Comment: Passing in the strategy still means you cannot rely on the type to know that any specific rules have been enforced.  I could pass `(fun _ _ -> true)` as the strategy and always get back an `AuthenticatedManager`.  If you want to use the type to ensure that the rules are met, I would at least make the strategy the first parameter, and make the function that takes the strategy parameter `internal`.  Then you could partially apply different strategies, and/or allow friend assemblies to support your Mock, without allowing any strategy to be passed by the consumer.